# How to change the locale or language used for Google Translate dropdown?

Tags: google-chrome, language, locale, google-translate

I am using this website:
https://subtitlestranslator.com/en/translate.php

After uploading some subtitles, it lets me to choose the language but the language is shown in the current location I am in rather than the language used in my Google account (English). How can I fix it so it only shows the options in English? Otherwise I don't know which item means what.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From
[Change Chrome languages & translate webpages](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/173424?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop):

> **Change your default language**
>
> You can select the language Chrome translates the page into.
>
> 1. On your computer, open Chrome.
> 2. At the top right, hamburger menu, click **Settings**.
> 3. On the left, click **Languages**.
> 4. Under “Google Translate,” click **Translate into this language**.
> 5. Select the language that you want from the language list.

Comment: I had this set to English there too so that wasn't it. I turned that option off, still the same. I had to use VPN to get it to show up in English.

Comment: Does in happen with Chrome in Incognito mode?

Comment: Yes unfortunately.